# Replace repeated value based on sequence size - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a 2D matrix composed of ones and zeros.

```
mat = [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
       1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0
       0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1];
```

I need to find all consecutive repetitions of ones in each row and replace all ones with zeros **only** when the sequence size is smaller than 5 (5 consecutive ones):

```
mat = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
       1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
       0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
```

Any suggestion on how to approach this problem would be very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `diff` to find the start and end points of the runs of 1, and some logic based on that to zero out the runs which are too short. Please see the below code with associated comments

```
% Input matrix of 0s and 1s
mat = [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
       1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0
       0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1];
% Minimum run length of 1s to keep   
N = 5;

% Get the start and end points of the runs of 1. Add in values from the
% original matrix to ensure that start and end points are always paired
d = [mat(:,1),diff(mat,1,2),-mat(:,end)];
% Find those start and end points. Use the transpose during the find to
% flip rows/cols and search row-wise relative to input matrix.
[cs,r] = find(d.'>0.5);  % Start points
[ce,~] = find(d.'<-0.5); % End points
c = [cs, ce];            % Column number array for start/end
idx = diff(c,1,2) < N;   % From column number, check run length vs N

% Loop over the runs which didn't satisfy the threshold and zero them
for ii = find(idx.')
    mat(r(ii),c(ii,1):c(ii,2)-1) = 0;
end
```

---

If you want to throw legibility out of the window, this can be condensed for a slightly faster and denser version, based on the exact same logic:

```
[c,r] = find([mat(:,1),diff(mat,1,2),-mat(:,end)].'); % find run start/end points
for ii = 1:2:numel(c)     % Loop over runs
    if c(ii+1)-c(ii) < N  % Check if run exceeds threshold length
        mat(r(ii),c(ii):c(ii+1)-1) = 0; % Zero the run if not
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm! Could you explain the reasoning behind the transposing when finding the start and end points?

Comment: Sure, MATLAB typically works column-wise, so I could have done `[r,ce] = find(d>0.5)`, but the values of `r` (the row number) for example would have been `[2,2,2,3,2,1,2,3,...]`, so all of the rows are jumbled up, and neighbouring elements do not correspond to the start/end of a run on a single row. However, by flipping it (and flipping the outputs from row/col to col/row), we get all of the column indices for row 1, then all of row 2, etc. Because I made sure there was always a paired start/end in `d`, these can then be matched up in `[cs,ce]` without any further reshuffling

Comment: There might have been a way to avoid the transpose which is more elegant, I didn't spent much time trying to find it after convincing myself the above would work :)

Answer (score 0):

The vectorized solution by @Wolfie is nice and concise, but a bit hard to understand and far from the wording of the problem. Here is a direct translation of the problem using loops. It has the advantage of being easier to understand and is slightly faster with less memory allocations, which means it will work for huge inputs.

```
[m,n] = size(mat);
for i = 1:m
    j = 1;
    while j <= n
        seqSum = 1;
        if mat(i,j) == 1
            for k = j+1:n
                if mat(i,k) == 1
                    seqSum = seqSum + 1;
                else
                    break
                end
            end
            if seqSum < 5
                mat(i,j:j+seqSum-1) = 0;
            end
        end
        j = j + seqSum;
    end
end
```

Comment: Do you have a benchmark for "slightly faster"? Also it's easy enough to propose additional answers without trying to degrade existing ones :)

Comment: Just do a `tic` .. `toc` or a `timeit` for a wide range of inputs and compare the results. I see about 6% speedup with a big memory reduction with my version because it doesn't allocate temporary arrays. That has nothing to do with your solution, each approach has its own merits and drawbacks, that's a well established observation. See, e.g., [this MATLAB answer](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/12504-is-vectorized-code-always-faster-than-loops-any-exceptions#answer_17092) and the linked example theirin. ..cont'd.

Comment: ... I used and taught MATLAB for two decades and couldn't grasp your solution at a glance. My answer, however, is more like telling a story; look into the rows, whenever you find a `1` keep track of the next `1`s and if these are less than 5, zero them out. Finally it's a good practice and knowledge to carry along for other languages like C/C++/Julia, etc.